# How to print hardware models for humans

Tags: hardware

Occasionally I want to check what exact model of hardware component I am using. I don't really care about extreme detail things like what brand of capacitor they used on the Motherboard in position xyz. I just want to know what is the exact model of my motherboard, ram, video card and so on, usually because I'm trying to shop for compatible hardware or look for drivers. So basically all I need is one line per important piece of hardware showing pretty much what the box said that it came in.

How can I do this in Linux from the command line?

What I've tried:

- `neofetch` is the best thing I've found but it only shows CPU and GPU. It doesn't say the RAM model or frequency, hard drive model or motherboard model.
- `lshw` prints 517 lines of gibberish that I can never make heads or tails out of. This is clearly some kind of technical tool, not something for people that just want to know what models of hardware they have and are too lazy to pop the case and look inside with a flashlight.

Comment: The type of information you want appears to be at the beginning of `lshw`'s output.  The `head` command can be used to only get the first X lines of output from a command.  `lshw | head -n 15` tells me the model ("product") and manufacturer ("vendor").  It's not as compact/straightforward as `inxi` described by @Freddy below though.

Comment: @LawrenceC It is not, otherwise I would not be asking the question. Interested parties can see the accepted answer for details.

Comment: You could also customize neofetch to display what you want.  https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Customizing-Info

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[inxi](https://github.com/smxi/inxi) is another tool of this kind.
The default output is only 2 lines, the full output on my machine (`-F`) has 29 lines, with memory info (`-m`) a few lines more.
Options `-x`, `-xx` and `-xxx` add more verbose information to each item like vendor:product ID or serial number if you need them.

[Screenshots](https://smxi.org/docs/inxi-screenshots.htm)

Try it:

```
inxi
inxi -Fm
sudo inxi -Fmxx
```

---

Standard tools are `lspci`, `lsusb` and `lscpu` if you need information about your hardware.

Answer (score 12):

`lshw`'s default output format is, IMO, excessively verbose.  You may find the `-short` output format useful, it's a simple one line per device human-readable summary.

The `-json` option produces output that is easy to parse unambiguously in a variety of languages - e.g. perl and python have JSON parsing libraries, and you can use `jq` on the command line or in a shell script to process json data and extract the information you want.  See `man lshw` for details.

Another tool you may find useful is `dmidecode`.  From `man dmidecode`:

> `dmidecode` is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some
> say SMBIOS) table contents in a human-readable format.
>
> This table contains a description of the system's hardware
> components, as well as other useful pieces of information
> such as serial numbers and BIOS revision. Thanks to this
> table, you can retrieve this information without having to
> probe for the actual hardware.
>
> While this is a good point in terms of report speed and
> safeness, this also makes the presented information
> possibly unreliable.

Comment: The "-short" format for lshw is sometimes a little *too* concise.  For example, it merely notes that I've got an NVME drive, without saying what model it is.

Comment: yes.  and `ls` without `-l` doesn't print the permissions, size, or timestamp. programs often have various options to do different things.   lshw's `-short` option outputs a summary without many details. If you want detailed output, use the default output or the `-json` option.